# How to use GNU tools to extract and merge two substrings of the same string?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

Suppose I get the following result after doing a `grep "emailed"`

```
/home/John/logs/2013-07-10.171222-0400EDT.html:I have emailed Mark. Thanks
```

I want to extract the date from this so that my output looks like -

```
2013-07-10:I have emailed Mark. Thanks
```

How can I do this using any one of the GNU tools? In particular, I want to pipe the output of grep to the tool. I suppose that `sed` may be the tool that does this, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
$ <grep-command> | sed -r 's|^.*/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})[^:]*:(.*)|\1:\2|'
```

... ought to work. In detail:

1. `-r` tells sed to use [extended regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html).
2. `s|a(b)c(d)|\1:\2|` says "match `a` then `b` then `c` then `d`, and replace the whole thing with `b:d` (the first and second parenthesized items, separated by a `:`", where `a` .. `d` are:

   a. `^.*/` - everything (`.*`) from the beginning of the line (`^`) to a `/` character (which is why we're using `|` instead of `/` to separate the clauses of the `s` command).

   b. `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}` - a digit (`[0-9]`) four times (`{4}`), followed by a `-`, followed by a digit twice, etc.

   c. `[^:]*:` - anything that *isn't* a `:` (`[^:]*`), followed by a `:`.

   d. `.*` - everything else.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Could you please explain what your above command is doing?

Comment: Or better yet `sed -n -r '/emailed/s/|...|p` to get rid of the `grep` altogether.